# Ansible pip output

Tags: pip, ansible

I'm using ansible and pip with a requirements.txt. It would be nice to know the progress of the install (with respect to which requirement lines have been processed). Is there a way to know in real time what lines have been processed?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question - doesn't pip tell you the progress during the install? if it ever stops you will see where it had an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you are using the `pip module` to install packages on a target machine.

Due to ansible concepts there cannot be such a possibility:
Ansible is designed to automate the tasks on remote systems in a parallel way. Just imagine your playbook concerns a group of hosts (which all should install packages): How could there be a sensible output in real time?

The only thing you can do is to capture the output with `register` and to print it with `debug`, but that would be after execution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that this is by design. I thought as much.